# When field1 = x1 on certain date, change field1 equal = x2 to x3 on same date

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with time info.
WorkDate, EmployeeID, TypeOfPay, TimeSpent, etc
There will be more than one line per WorkDate.  If TypeOfPay = x1 (for any WorkDate for a certain EmployeeID)  then change all TypeOfPay = x2 to x3 (for the same WorkDate and EmployeeID)

Original Data

```
WorkDate    EmployeeID  TypeOfPay   TimeSpent
2015-11-01         154         x1   8
2015-11-01         154         x2   2.5
2015-11-01         154         x2   1.1
2015-11-01         154         x4   1
2015-11-01         212         x1   8
2015-11-01         212         x4   4
2015-11-01         402         x2   7
```

Results

```
WorkDate    EmployeeID  TypeOfPay   TimeSpent
2015-11-01         154        x1    8
2015-11-01         154        x3    2.5
2015-11-01         154        x3    1.1
2015-11-01         154        x4    1
2015-11-01         212        x1    8
2015-11-01         212        x4    4
2015-11-01         402        x2    7
```

Thanks in advance
Gerry

Comment: I tried a few things with no luck.  It`s the criteria that has me stumped and how to go about it. For each EmployeeID and common WorkDate, if there is an x1 and an x2, change x2 to x3.  I thought of using Case or a self join, but don`t know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will look something like this. I am assuming the table name to be test1

```
update test1 a join test1 b on  
a.workdate = b.workdate and a.employeeid=b.employeeid 
set b.typeofpay = 'x3' 
where a.typeofpay = 'x1' and b.typeofpay = 'x2'
```

This query works fine on mysql. The query will be almost similar for sql server.

For SQL Server the following query will work

```
update b
set b.typeofpay = 'x3' 
from test1 a join test1 b on  
    a.workdate = b.workdate and a.employeeid=b.employeeid   
where a.typeofpay = 'x1' and b.typeofpay = 'x2'
```

Comment: Shivanand
I get the following error when I try to run this.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
Thanks
Gerry

Comment: The above query will work on MySql. For Sql server, The syntax is a little different. Please see the edited answer for SQL Server.